# Spring-data migrate to new active fork of querydsl at: https://github.com/OpenFeign/querydsl?

Tags: spring-data

The querydsl project has struggled to be maintained, as has been asked in previous questions here like: "What's the latest status of QueryDSL?"

There is a new active fork of querydsl at: https://github.com/OpenFeign/querydsl, where they have release a version up to 5.2 and are working on a 6.0.0 release.  I'd like to encourage the spring-data team to look into migrating over to this new active fork of querydsl so at a minimum at least all the dependencies get upgraded and maybe there are bug fixes and improvements too.

Hopefully it works that spring-data can switch to this new active fork of querydsl. And possibly other Spring projects, if they use querydsl too.